# How can I make the screen scroll up and down with the scroll thumb?

Tags: android, gridview, scrollbar

I am new to android development. Can anyone help me solve this issue?
Whenever i am trying to move the scroll bar downwards,the entire screen is moving upwards.
The XML I have created is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/backButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button" />


<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="190dp"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scrollbarSize="20dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_track"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used LinearLayout as your container to show the view . And if you don't define the orientation in it then by default it takes "horizontal" orientation. In your case you have give orientation as vertical
change your linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

with below:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Stating the android:orientation as "vertical"